# Control text justification

Tags: r

I am trying to create an input file for another program that is space-delimited.  I'm pasting together the contents of multiple columns and having problems when the number have different lengths due to what appears to be a default right-justify in R.  For example:

```
row_id       monthly_spend
 123            4.55
 567           24.64
 678          123.09
```

becomes :

```
row_id:123 monthly_spend:  4.55
row_id:567 monthly_spend: 24.64
row_id:678 monthly_spend:123.09
```

while what I need is this:

```
row_id:123 monthly_spend:4.55
row_id:567 monthly_spend:24.64
row_id:678 monthly_spend:123.09
```

the code I'm using is derived from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940573/r-convert-data-frame-to-input-file-improve-performance) and looks like this:

```
paste(row_id, monthly_spend, sep=":", collapse=" ")
```

i've tried formatting the columns as numeric or integer without any change.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you use `dput` to provide us with the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put your vectors into a data.frame (if they are not already)
you can use:

```
apply(sapply(names(myDF),  function(x)
    paste(x, myDF[, x], sep=":")  ), 1, paste, collapse=" ")

#  [1] "row_id:123 monthly_spend:4.55"  
#  [2] "row_id:567 monthly_spend:24.64" 
#  [3] "row_id:678 monthly_spend:123.09"
```

or alternatively:

```
do.call(paste, lapply(names(myDF), function(x) paste0(x, ":", myDF[, x])))
```

`sprintf` is also an option.  You've got many ways of going about it

sample data used:

```
myDF <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"row_id       monthly_spend
123            4.55
567           24.64
678          123.09")
```

Comment: this works really well. actually faster than my original code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

assuming the data frame is called df

```
 write.table(as.data.frame(sapply(1:ncol(df),FUN=function(x)paste(rep(colnames(df)[x],nrow(df)),df[,x],sep=":"))),"someFileName",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=" ");
```

equivalent to following substeps:

```
# generating the column separated records
df_cp<-sapply(1:ncol(df),FUN=function(x)paste(rep(colnames(df)[x],nrow(df)),df[,x],sep=":"));
### casting to data frame
df_cp<-as.data.frame(df_cp);
### writing out to disk
write.table(df_cp,"someFileName",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

With your data snippet:

```
df <- read.table(text = "row_id       monthly_spend
 123            4.55
 567           24.64
 678          123.09", header = TRUE)
```

The we can `paste` together but employ the `format` function with `trim = TRUE` to take care of stripping the spaces you don't want:

```
with(df, paste("row_id:", row_id,
               "monthly_spend:", format(monthly_spend, trim = TRUE)))
```

Which gives:

```
> with(df, paste("row_id:", row_id,
+                 "monthly_spend:", format(monthly_spend, trim = TRUE)))
[1] "row_id: 123 monthly_spend: 4.55"   "row_id: 567 monthly_spend: 24.64" 
[3] "row_id: 678 monthly_spend: 123.09"
```

If you need this in a data frame before writing out to file, use:

```
newdf <- with(df, data.frame(foo = paste("row_id:", row_id,
                                         "monthly_spend:",
                                         format(monthly_spend, trim = TRUE))))
newdf

> newdf
                                foo
1   row_id: 123 monthly_spend: 4.55
2  row_id: 567 monthly_spend: 24.64
3 row_id: 678 monthly_spend: 123.09
```

When you write this out, the columns will be justified as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general answer (any number of variables), assuming your data is in a data.frame `dat`:

```
x <- mapply(names(dat), dat, FUN = paste, sep = ":")
write.table(x, file = stdout(),
               quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

And you can replace `stdout()` with a filename.